# Get the latest part of the URL as an input to a PHP file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I *only* have two files at my directory of `http://www.example.com/members/`: an `.htaccess` file and an `index.php` file:

---

*<sub>The contents of the `.htaccess` file:</sub>*

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?code=$1
```

*<sub>The contents of the `index.php` file:</sub>*

```
<?php var_dump($_GET);
```

---

I also have a bunch of URLs in the format of "`http://www.example.com/members/nnnn`". I just want to get the `nnnn` part in my PHP file while having the URL **intact**.

But now, if I request the URL of `http://www.example.com/members/13`, I would like to get the `13` in my `index.php` file; while, what I get instead, is:

```
array(1) { ["code"]=> string(9) "index.php" }
```

The `13` is not there!! So, how do I change the `.htaccess` code to get the desired behavior?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I would suggest to have a look at the $_SERVER array and check what elements have the url in it. This might be different per installation. But $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] might be a good one. Then use strrpos() to get the last occurance of a slash (not the trailing one). This can also be done usint $_GET['code'] but this is only extra effort

Comment: btw: if you omit a [R] or [L] after your rule, does it not default to [R]?

Comment: @IvoP Wow! the `$_SERVER` contains more than what I expected :) Hmm, so now, sounds like I don't even need the `index.php?code=$1` in the `.htaccess` file, thank you, you're awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the `.htaccess` file:

> Make sure your `.htaccess` and index files are in a same folder.

```
# set directory index
DirectoryIndex index.php

# No directory listings
IndexIgnore *

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Uncomment the following line if your webserver's URL is not directly related to physical file paths.
    # Also uncomment it if you are on 1&1 hosting
    #RewriteBase /

    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !
    RewriteRule    ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$ index.php?code=$1&code2=$2&code3=$3    [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And if you want more levels of paths; then, just add the following before the `$` sign in the last `RewriteRule`:

```
/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?
```

Using that, the URL of:

```
www.example.com/members/13
```

will become:

```
www.example.com/members/index.php?code=13
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I appricate it :) I've forgotten to mention that I want the URL intact!!! (I've just updated the question :)

Comment: Regardless of the code causes the URL to get modified; It also redirects to a weird URL: `/home/example/domains/example/public_html/members/index.php?code=13` :o The files are on a shared host, BTW :\

Comment: Thank you :) I've tested it, it does the same as before :(

Comment: try [QSA,L] instead of NC,L and let me know to edit the answer

Comment: I just tried it with `[QSA,L]` and Yes!! It did work! :)) Could you please, elaborate on the code with some explanations :)

Comment: Please elaborate on how it operates and prohibits the URL from being modified and so on...

Comment: With your latest edit, the `$_GET['code']` resolves back to the undesired `index.php`!!!! While in the previous edition, it worked well!!!

Comment: I've tested it again; now, the server responds with an error code of `404 Not Found`.

Comment: try it again I give you same my htaccess file

Comment: Now, your first code works; Thank you. However, it works for only one level of path, while the previous workaround had that as a feature. Thanks again :)

Comment: welcome, I am ready to help you any time and if you want for more than one level of path just tell me

Comment: now I edited the answer to new answer tested by me please read it to the end

Comment: You did it, thank you for your kind commitment; I really appreciate it :)

Comment: note that when using these kind of rewriterules, you may need a lot of them when the url could consist of 1, 2 or 3, elements. And it grows worse when adding conditions like "when the second part equals 'order' then it is followed by a number " etc. I prefer to rewrite it to 1 index.php and do all the splitting in PHP. So one would also avoid a fast growing tree of rule that might contradict in some cases. The regular expressions quickly become hard to understand, and may not cover all possible characters, like fi. a dash -. And in PHP it is possible to use more than a single line to get it

Comment: I would when it should be done this way, change the part `[a-zA-Z0-9]` to `[^/]`  (meaning: any character, but not a /. That way it still works when you later want to allow a dash, a + or other "strange" character there

Answer (score 1):

To have more space than using the comments I did [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467302/get-the-latest-part-of-the-url-as-an-input-to-a-php-file#comment79889658_46467302):

I would write the `.htaccess` file as:

```
RewriteEngine On
# if given url does point to exsiting Dir or File:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
# Then do nothing and stop
RewriteRule ^  - [L]

# still here: so go to index.php to execute
RewriteRule ^.* index.php [L,QSA]
```

In `index.php`, I would then check [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) to find the information. I leave you with [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php), [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) or even [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to do your thing.

Comment: This is really nice :) and the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` resolves my issue, thank you :)